# Generating full planet tiles from OpenStreetMap data?

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, mapnik, osm2pgsql, mbtiles

```
        i am tested using two scenarios,
```

1) First, i am used switch2osm for tile rendering. its good it handles many things. But it takes long days to pre-render all tiles and  it takes huge memory in TB.

2) Second, i am used tilemill to generate MBTiles and served using https://github.com/chelm/mbtiles-server But i dont know how much efficient for larger using.

Other than this, Is any other way serving Tiles for whole planet in efficient way.

Machine config : 1.5 TB and 128 GB main memory.

Comment: I serve them using Geoserver, Geowebcache and Postgres/PostGIS

Comment: thanks @MarkC, in Geoserver, Is it possible to generate tiles for full planet. if yes, then what about machine config ?

Comment: yes it is, you have plenty of memory an 1.5Tb is enough for the planet file in PostGres, but if you want a whole planet tiled before serving, you have not scratched the surface for disk space needed. No need to pre-tile (called seeding) anyway, just do it on demand and let Geowebcache handle it with disk quotas. I would stick another 1.5Tb drive on it, config GeoWebCache to use it for it's cache and let the users create the cache on demand as they access it. Only the first user will experience any delay then the tile is cached for future use.

Comment: Why do you want to create a full planet tileset anyway?

Comment: As mentioned before using switch2osm i have imported whole planet in about configuration machine but its very slow in rendering. Even though like Geowebcache it also having mod-tile, its very slow in showing tiles. so i prefer to pre-render in mod-tiles. Now for pre-rendering take very long days. so i prefer to have some alternative choice for that.

Comment: i don't want full planet tileset right now, i wants quick rendering tiles on web page. As you said if i go with Geoserver and Geowebcache its how much speed in showing map ?. How did you import postgis planet db to Geoserver?

Comment: As per SE Policies, you should ask these as very specific questions after doing some research ..

Comment: okay @MarkC. Suggest me a efficient way among above two(switch2OSM and Geoserver) Methods.